# How to Center dynamic text in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new at coding but it feels like I am stuck on some stupid level thing!!! I want my dynamic text on center of my page and slightly top of my button. But long text just overlapping my button. I want both of them to adjust in screen and stay in completely center of page no matter how long the text is. **See this** [image]

And small text starts from left which I also want to be in center. **See this**[image]

Here is my code

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        const arr = [
            { title: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book." },
            { title: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.' },
            { title: "Name2" },
            { title: "Name3" },
            { title: "Name4" }
        ];

        function onClickHandler() {
            const ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
            const item = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
            ul.innerHTML = `
        <p style= "position: absolute; text-align: center; top: 42%; ">
            ${item.title}
        </p>`;
        }
    </script>
    <title> Random Site</title>

<body>
        <button onclick="onClickHandler()" style= " position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;">Button</button>
    <ul></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `<ul>` tag for displaying the text? You can create a `<div>`, and then add the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one thing you might be overlooking, by default the `ul` has padding on the left, you can remove this by just adding `style="padding: 0;"` to your `ul` element.  Also you can utilize modern CSS by flexing the content of the body.

Edit: pro-tip you can inspect the outcome of your HTML/CSS by inspecting the elements. Hovering the elements and/or selecting them you'll see what styling is applied to the elements you are trying to style. Have a look at [this post](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/how-to-inspect#:%7E:text=What%20does%20%27inspect%20element%27%20mean,live%20inside%20the%20browser%20window.)

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        const arr = [
            { title: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book." },
            { title: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.' },
            { title: "Name2" },
            { title: "Name3" },
            { title: "Name4" }
        ];

        function onClickHandler() {
            const ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
            const item = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
            ul.innerHTML = `
        <p>
            ${item.title}
        </p>`;
        }
    </script>
    <title> Random Site</title>

<body style="display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse; justify-content: center; align-items:center; height: 100vh; marign: 0; padding: 10px;">
        <button onclick="onClickHandler()">Button</button>
        <ul style="padding: 0;"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works so perfect. Thanks bro!!! And yea I copy pasted the js code so I forgot that I am using "ul" and obviously it starts from left always until you change it's properties. I could have never caught that thing lol

Answer (score 0):

To stay with your way, meaning not using flex, or better ccs grid, an old fashioned way...

I put style in standalone instead of html to be clearer.

```js
const arr = [{
    title: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
  },
  {
    title: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.'
  },
  {
    title: "Name2"
  },
  {
    title: "Name3"
  },
  {
    title: "Name4"
  }
];

function onClickHandler() {
  const ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  const item = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  ul.innerHTML = `<p>${item.title}</p>`;
}
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="onClickHandler()">Button</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Text is always just on top of button.

Comment: I think overlapping issue is solved but the small text still starts from left... Can you look again please bro?!

Comment: @solo I don't understand. Did you try the snippet? Big text is not overlapping

Comment: Yea bro I said overlapping issue solved. But the second issue was still remained in your code " small text starts from left side and not from center" But Someone corrected that too that I was using "ul" and obviously ul have left padding by default so Everything works perfect now. Thanks Bro

Comment: ok great, happy coding!